# Can a conky script display a simple PNG image?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, conky

Conky newbie. I have a PNG image of a monthly calendar with transparency. I can't figure out how to write a conky script to simply display this in the middle of my desktop over my wallpaper. I have an updating wallpaper, so I want to use conky. I don't want to use a wallpaper with a calendar on it, in other words. Is this possible?

More info: What's the easiest way to show a monthly calendar with transparency over my desktop wallpaper (Ubuntu 18.10)? Something similar to [Large Calendar for Raindar](https://www.deviantart.com/r3ginald/art/Calendar-Notes-138348718). Note function would not be required. I have an updating wallpaper, so I don't want to use a wallpaper with a calendar on it.

Answer (score 2):

Conky does have an `image` object:
http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html

You would use it similar to:
`${image /some/path/to/image.png -p 250,0 -s 80x80}`

It is likely your mileage may vary with this one.

---- Responding to comment ----
I recommend getting rid of Conky Manager. You can launch conky in the background with a simple script. Beauty here is you can test the script by removing the `&` until you have it all working. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10s
killall conky
cd "/home/username/.conky/someFolder"
conky -c "/home/username/.conky/someFolder/.conkyrc" &
```

... such that `.conkyrc` is your conky file.
HTH

Comment: Thanks @Mark! I guess I don't know how to properly create a Conky widget, or have Conky Manager load my widget. Under `~/.conky` I created a widget folder and widget file containing the `image` object, but Conky Manager still only lists those that came with installation.